# heroku cannot find module bcrypt-as-promised?

Tags: json, node.js, heroku, bcrypt

app works in localhost but when I am trying to deploy in heroku, it gets uploaded but app crashes when visited. why did heroku not install bcrypt-as-promised? These are my package.json scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "prestart": "babel -d ./build ./server ",
    "start": "node ./build/",
    "bundle": "webpack --config ./webpack.prod.config.js --progress --colors",
    "build": "relay-compiler --src ./js/ --schema ./server/schema.graphql",
    "update-schema": "babel-node ./scripts/updateSchema.js"
  },
```

and this is my error on heroku logs -t:

```
Starting process with command `node ./build/`
2017-09-26T04:03:12.946916+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:471
2017-09-26T04:03:12.946928+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2017-09-26T04:03:12.946928+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-09-26T04:03:12.946927+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2017-09-26T04:03:12.946929+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'bcrypt-as-promised'
```

this is my first time using bcrypt-as-promised and I am so confused. is it different on other module? what makes it not installed in heroku?

Comment: Are you sure that you have added `bcrypt-as-promised` in package.json, if yes then try to reinstall node_modules using `npm i`

Comment: yees but i fixed this using another package bcryptjs